# How to use a single .war for several grails environments in AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I run several environments of my Grails application up in Elastic Beanstalk.  It would be a big timesaver  to not have to build and upload different .war files just for the different environments (I have all the environmental differences passed in as system properties in the 'container' configuration area, so there is no external config file).  As per this article http://mrhaki.blogspot.ca/2011/02/grails-goodness-one-war-to-rule-them.html, it is possible to use a single .war and set the environment dynamically by passing the grails.env property, but it doesn't seem possible to do so as beanstalk limits you to a predefined set of named system properties (JDBC_CONNECTION_STRING, PARAM1, PARAM2, etc)

What would be my best approach here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out you can pass arbitrary parameters, including environment variables, to the container via the 'JVM Command Line Options' field in the 'container' area of the configuration.

```
-Dgrails.env=DesiredEnvironmentName
```

Works like a charm, I'm now using a single .war for all environments.

Answer (score 0):

Set PARAM1 to the name of your config file,

then in Config.groovy

```
grails.config.locations = [ System.getProperty("PARAM1") ]
```

Alternatively, you could just store a different configuration for each of your environments in the database via something like the dynamic config plugin - http://grails.org/plugin/dynamic-config

Comment: I want to avoid any environment specific configuration file (or any file in general, as that complicates vanilla deployment of a .war to beanstalk instances)